# Segue between 2 view controllers (modal) via UIButton crash in Xcode 6 and Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6

so I am practicing iOs programming and I can't seem to find a solution to my problem. I have a "loginViewController" where I want my UIButton "Creer un compte" to modally present my "register" view controller. Here is the issue, when I fire up the simulator and I click the button, it crashes and bring me to the first line of AppDelegate,

"class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, Thread1 signal SIGABRT."

I did the segue by control dragging my UIButton to the Register view controller.

Here is the code:

```
import UIKit
```

class LoginViewController: UIViewController {

```
@IBOutlet weak var LoginScreenImage: UIImageView!

@IBOutlet weak var codeTextField: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var nipTextField: UITextField!

@IBAction func showRegisterPage(sender: AnyObject) {

    let registerViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("RegisterViewController") as RegisterViewController
    self.showViewController(registerViewController, sender: self)
}



let client = Client.sharedInstance

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    LoginScreenImage.image = UIImage(named: "UQAMLOGO")
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}




@IBAction func connect() {
    let code = codeTextField.text
    let nip = nipTextField.text

    if code != nil && nip != nil {
        client.login(code, password: nip, callback: { (response) in
            if let response = response {
                if response.status == LoginStatus.Ok {
                    // Good login.
                    let homeViewController = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("HomeViewController") as HomeViewController

                    self.showViewController(homeViewController, sender: self)
                }
            } else {
                // Error
            }
        })
    }
}
```

}

and the RegisterViewController:

```
import UIKit
```

class RegisterViewController: UIViewController {

```
@IBOutlet weak var firstNameTextField: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var lastNameTextField: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var emailTextField: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var passwordTextField: UITextField!

let client = Client.sharedInstance

override func viewDidLoad() {



super.viewDidLoad()
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.



}


override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@IBAction func register() {

    let firstName = firstNameTextField.text
    let lastName = lastNameTextField.text
    let email = emailTextField.text
    let password = passwordTextField.text

    if(firstName != nil && lastName != nil && email != nil && password != nil){

        client.register(email, password: password, firstName: firstName, lastName: lastName, callback: {(response) in
            if let response = response{
                if response.status == RegisterStatus.Ok{
                    let loginViewController = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("LoginViewController") as LoginViewController

                    self.showViewController(loginViewController, sender: self)
                }
            }else{
                //erreur
            }
            })
    }
}
```

}

I tried to do it programatically, tried to reset the viewControllers to their default class (UIViewController).

Thanks for the help everyone,

Charles

Answer (score 0):

When you make a segue from a button to another controller, the segue is performed without any code needed -- you should delete the showRegisterPage method. I'm not sure if that's your only problem, but you should delete that method, and see if you still get the error.

Comment: Hi rdelmar, I just tried to delete it and it still doesn't work.

Comment: @cvinette, does it perform the segue, or does it crash before that happens?

Comment: It crashes before it happens. I tried to bind the same button to another view and it works without issue. But as soon as I drag it so that it performs a modal segue, it crashes and bring me to appdelegate.